Playing multiple audio tracks at the same time
I am having trouble attempting to create properly working audio for my game. The audio seems to be just fine when just the music is playing, but when the game initiates a sound effect, it can be delayed, choppy, and act generally strange. This is the code I currently have for playing audio:
function playsfx(sfx) {
    let newAudio = sfx.cloneNode(true)
    newAudio.volume = sfx.volume
    newAudio.play()
}

I use it for every sound effect except the music.
I have attempted a simple play and pause; it causes less delay but a lot more choppiness. I am not willing to use Web Audio API.

What is sfx ? Without the complete code it's not possible to reproduce your error.

sfx is the audio element created with new Audio().

You may want to use let newAudio = new Audio(). And could you post code that reproduces your error?
